# How do I fix Coversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
con.open();
SqlCommamd comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Debt_Tab values('"+Textbox1.text+"')",con);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Textbox1 I is declared as a `DateTime` in my Sql table.

Comment: Look up how Parameters are used with ADO.Net commands in the documentation. Then convert your string from the TextBox into a DateTime and set the Parameter representing your Date field as DateTime. Be aware how a Date looks as string is culture depending.

Comment: You should never concatenate user provided data (like your textbox) to create a SqlCommand. That is a security bug called SQL Injection. You could avoid that bug using parametrized queries as you have already been told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use this hope this will work**

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Textbox1.text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to format a date. To be sure that the database gets the correct format I suggest that you parse the date by specifying a culture.

For desktop applications, this is easy since the OS is configured for a specific format, while for web applications the user uses their own preferred format (unless you have specified something else).

To parse using the OS culture:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(Textbox1.Text)
```

To parse using a specific culture:

```
var swedish = new CultureInfo("sv_se");
var date = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text, swedish);
```

Another thing. There is something seriously wrong with your code. It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You need to use a parameterized query instead.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(con);
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Debt_Tab values(@date)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Convert.ToDateTime()
```

example:-

```
con.open();
SqlCommamd comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Debt_Tab values('"+ Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox1.text).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") +"')",con);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way to validate the date

```
bool res;
  DateTime Date;
  string myDate = Textbox1.text;
  res = DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out Date);
  if(res)
  {
   // Validation or conversion success and result will be available in Date variable
  }
  else 
  {
     // conversion Fail
  }
```